# Decrypting an encrypted file corrupts the file? Android - Java

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am using the following code to encrypt/decrypt:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


public class CryptoUtils {
    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES";

    public static void encrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    public static void decrypt(String key, File inputFile, File outputFile)
            throws CryptoException {
        doCrypto(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, inputFile, outputFile);
    }

    private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile,
                                 File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
        try {
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PAdding");
            cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            inputStream.read(inputBytes);

            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(outputBytes);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException
                | InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException ex) {
            throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file", ex);
        }
    }

    public static class CryptoException extends Exception {

        public CryptoException() {
        }

        public CryptoException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
            super(message, throwable);
        }
    }
}
```

I can both encrypt and decrypt a video file.
However, I am not able to play the decrypted file, encrypted by the same code.

The original file: http://www.megafileupload.com/hSTZ/a.mp4

The encrypted file: http://www.megafileupload.com/hSU2/encrypted-a.mp4

The decrypted file: http://www.megafileupload.com/hSU1/decrypted-final-a.mp4

The first 16 bytes of the decrypted file are different from the original file. The length is the same.

Comment: I'm not too strong on crypto in java, and especially under Android, but I am concerned that I'm not seeing how you pass your IV from the encrypt function to the decrypt function.  CBC mode uses that initialization vector to obfuscate the first block of crypto output so the same plain text will yield completely different crypto text even with the same key.  If you decrypt using a different IV than you used on encrypt, the decrypt will succeed, but the first block (16 bytes) will be scrambled.  Try explicitly providing your IV (hardcode it for testing if you like) and see if that works.

Comment: I didn't mention my suspicion, but in .NET in C#, if you have CBC mode and don't specify your IV, the algorithm will randomly generate one.  Typically you would write that as the first block of the crypto output, then read it as the first block of crypto input for use preparing the algorithm for decrypting.  So either write your random IV into the beginning of your output file, or (for testing only) hardcode it into the program.  Note that a hardcoded IV loses all of the beneficial properties an IV exists to provide.  But for testing purposes I would try that.

Comment: Without knowing how you encrypted it, it is impossible to know what's the issue with the decryption code. I don't want to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Comment: @WDS I've downloaded the files. Indeed the wrong IV is the problem, but a solution cannot be provided as the question currently stands.

Comment: @ArtjomB. how can I add the salt code in there .. can you please help . Thanks

Comment: hey you have solvd this problem @manishKungwani

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that:

1. The file fits into memory.
2. The file size fits into an int.
3. `read()` fills the buffer.
4. The result of encryption or decryption fits into memory along with the source content.

There's no need for any of these assumptions.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    byte[] output = cipher.update(buffer, 0, count);
    outputStream.write(output);
}
outputStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
```

E&OE but you get the idea. You could make your life even simpler by using `CipherInput/OutputStreams,` but you lose touch with the crypto exceptions a bit that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help @EJP  but the change did not work .. the decrypted encrypted file does not play ..